# Why does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{x+1}}{x}$ converge to 0?

Tags: limits

As the title states, why does$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{x+1}}{x}$?  It seems like this would produce the indeterminate form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ at which point I would use L'Hospital's rule but I don't even know how to take the derivative of $(-1)^{x+1}$.

Could anyone show me why $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{x+1}}{x}$ converges to 0? (According to Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: $(-1)^{x+1}$ is always $\pm 1$, it doesn't go to $\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat Whoops, was a typo - meant $x\to\infty$.

Comment: L'Hospital obsession at its best.

Comment: We should really be using $n$ instead of $x$: the limit needs to go through integer values. Otherwise we'd have something like $(-1)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Always wondered why $n$ is an integer and $x$ is a real? (And $z$ a complex, for that matter.)

Comment: Who can say $(-1)^{x+1}=\pm 1$? How we can say $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}=\pm 1$?

Comment: Even if we allow for rational exponents of $-1$ the limit is still zero since $|(-1)^x|=|\exp(\log(-1)x)|=|\exp(\pi i x)|$ is bounded (branch cuts, yadda, yadda, yadda).

Comment: @David even if we have $(-1)^{x}$, and the value is $z\in \Bbb C$, $|z|=1$.

Comment: Picky remark: it's not the *limit* that converges to zero, but the *expression* which we're taking the limit of. The limit itself *equals* zero. (We say "I'm going to Spain" or "my destination is Spain", not "my destination is going to Spain".)

Comment: @Hans: Perhaps the action of going to Spain is your destination? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Not in the near future anyway! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$0\le\left|\dfrac{(-1)^{x+1}}{x}\right|=\dfrac{1}{x}\xrightarrow {x\to\infty} 0$$

Comment: When you don't know the value of $(-1)^\sqrt{2}$ how you can use $|.|$ for it. I think $|.|:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}=0\quad \mbox{and}\quad \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-1}{x}=0 $$
Therefore
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{x+1}}{x}=0 $$